# Tomahawk t:inputFileUpload results in validation error

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, character-encoding, tomahawk

I have a problem using the Tomahawk `t:inputFileUpload` component together with Primefaces input components.

I'm using this Tomahawk component because Primefaces converts "multipart/form-data" to another charset.

When i have special chars (like ã é ó..) in my form the p:message component is displaying 
`***Validation Error : the value is not valid***`

Here is the test project

**web.xml**

```
<display-name>TESTE_ANEXO</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
        <param-value>20m</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:head>
    <title><h:outputText value="#{msg.welcomeTitle}" /></title>
</h:head>

<body>
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" acceptcharset="UTF-8">
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>

    <p:selectOneMenu immediate="true" label="teste" id="teste">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="ããã" itemValue="ããã" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <t:inputFileUpload id="fileupload" value="#{meuBean.arquivo}" /> 
    <h:commandButton value="Enviar"  action="#{meuBean.enviar}" />
</h:form>
```

**MeuBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
public class MeuBean {

private UploadedFile arquivo;

public UploadedFile getArquivo() {
    return arquivo;
}

public void setArquivo(UploadedFile arquivo) {
    this.arquivo = arquivo;
}

public String enviar() {
    System.out.println("AA");
    System.out.println("Nome do arquivo enviado: " + arquivo.getName());
    System.out.println("Tipo do arquivo enviado: "
            + arquivo.getContentType());
    System.out.println("Tamanho do arquivo enviado: " + arquivo.getSize());

    return "ok";
}
}
```

**Dependency Versions**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomahawk21</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I fixed up your post as much as I could, but could you please add yourself what you mean by "adding special chars" and on what you base that Primefaces itself causes you problems; I can use the primefaces upload component just fine myself. Also you're using a rather old version of JSF, did you at least try with a more recent one?

Comment: Thanks for the help Gimby, this is my first question here in the community,so, sorry for the mistakes i did. I added some examples of the characters that i say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation error is coming from your dropdown menu containing "special characters". This is clearly explained in the answer of this related Q&A: [Validation Error: Value is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid). Most relevant part is cited below:

> In case you're already using `String`, make sure that the request character encoding is configured right. If it contains special characters and JSF is configured to render the output as UTF-8 but interpret the input as e.g. ISO-8859-1, then it will fail. See also a.o. [Unicode input retrieved via PrimeFaces input components become corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9634230).

If you think logically, Tomahawk has still not solved your encoding problem. Get rid of it, you don't need it as PrimeFaces already offers the same functionality with `<p:fileUpload>`.

If you still face the character encoding problem after configuring the character encoding filter as described in the aforementioned link, then you're most likely using a server which has a bug or requires additional configuration for its multipart/form-data parser.

Depending on whether the  server specific bug/configuration is manageable, you may need to switch back to Apache Commons FileUpload. It doesn't expose this encoding problem. You can find installation instructions in [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded). Basically, you need to add two JARs, install a servlet filter and set context param `primefaces.UPLOADER` to `commons`.

#### See also:

- [Filename characters encoding in Jsf 2.2 Upload vs. Apache Commons Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413585/filename-characters-encoding-in-jsf-2-2-upload-vs-apache-commons-upload)

Comment: Thanks BlausC!It works after adding the CharacterEncoddingFilter setting the request to UTF-8. Even with the primefaces component. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd like to note that `acceptcharset="UTF-8"` is unnecessary as it's ignored by sane browsers and broken in IE. Just remove it and rely on response encoding (which already defaults to UTF-8 in JSF2/Facelets).